# Insert HTML code inside SVG Text element

Tags: html, text, svg

I have an svg:text node, and I want to add HTML code inside it. Actually, my code is:

```
<text x="10" y="54" text-anchor="start" class="barLegend">Hello!</text>
```

And I want to put something like this:

```
<text x="10" y="54" text-anchor="start" class="barLegend"><a href='www.gmail.com'>Gmail</a></text>
```

Of course, I want the link working, but, it is just displaying all the HTML.

Any Idea?

Comment: As of SVG 2 `xlink` is deprecated and `href` will work just fine.

Answer (score 22):

Why not use an SVG `<a>` element in this case? Don't forget that the href needs to be xlink:href though. E.g.

```
<text x="10" y="54" text-anchor="start" class="barLegend"><a xlink:href='http://www.gmail.com'>Gmail</a></text>
```

Only SVG animation elements, descriptive elements (`<title>` or `<desc>`), text content child elements (`<tspan>` or `<textPath>`) or the SVG `<a>` element are allowed as children of text elements.

Comment: Mmmm, not clear which is the difference. Could you add an example?

Comment: an svg link element is in the svg namespace, an html link element is in the html namespace, otherwise they look pretty similar.

Answer (score 16):

You have to use the `foreignObject` tag, for example:

```
<foreignObject width="100" height="50"
                   requiredExtensions="http://example.com/SVGExtensions/EmbeddedXHTML">
  <body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <a href='www.gmail.com'>Gmail</a>
  </body>
</foreignObject>
```

See also here http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/extend.html and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG/Element/foreignObject

Comment: A foreignObject tag cannot be a child of a text element.

Comment: Thanks! That the way to use what I am looking for. Also, I found a link when someone has the same problem with D3: http://groups.google.com/group/d3-js/browse_thread/thread/77671e2884df4f1d

Comment: but where is the x and y coordinate ?

Answer (score 4):

Another solution here is to put an event on the item and use javascript to open the target URL .. and not use the  tag at all.