# Print Highstock with custom html

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using Highstock V 1.2.5

I want to print chart with some custom HTML details on top of it.

I have created a div in my JSP with custom HTMLand tried adding it before `body.appendChild(container);` into `exporting.js` But, It didn't work.

Second, I have tried creating HTMl file and adding `$("#tab2").html();` where `tab2` is my container. But, No luck with that.

When I open the exported HTML its different than what I get from `console.log($("#tab2").html())` and the copy it into HTML.

Is there any way to get container HTML into `.js` ?

Comment: Highcharts exporting module will hide all elements from site, and prints only chart. You can edit exporting module, to not hide some elements you don't want to.

Comment: @PawełFus: I am aware with that code, its just above `body.appendChild(container);`

Comment: But I want to get HTML. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit source in that way: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/497/

```
    // some custom code
    $(body).append('<div style="width:50px;height:50px; background-color: red"></div>');

    body.appendChild(container);

    // print
    win.focus(); // #1510
    win.print();
```

Comment: This is helpful. Still, Is it possible to get HTML using $("#tab2").html() and pass it along. ?

Comment: I'm not sure why do you want to use `html()`? That function without params returns HTML, so what next you want to do with it?

Comment: For example, this will work: `$(body).append($(container).html());`

Comment: Well, It works. But, I do not want to use `window.print`, I want `html` contained in SVG element and need to pass to some where.

Comment: I'm sorry, but didn't you say: "I want to print chart with some custom HTML details on top of it."? To get correct answer, you need to write proper question. I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946604/insert-html-code-inside-svg-text-element) will help you. Or just concat SVG from `chart.getSVG()` function with your custom HTML and then pass string somewhere you need.

Comment: Yes, I should have more clear title. Actually, I mentioned it in the body. Anyways, Thanks for the reply.