# how to place interactive button control with d3 charting library?

Tags: d3.js

I'm on a project which has a requirement to make data visualization. But more than just data visualization, there're some tricky interactive requirements.

Imagine a scatter plot, instead of little circles, clickable rectangles(like button) are placed on the chart. When user clicks on those buttons, the rectangles turns into some input fields, user can type make some inputs.

How to draw these buttons and input fields with d3.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research, the root of the problem is : how to put html in svg? Then there's plenty of questions and answers out there. Basically the solution is to use svg element: foreighObject. refer to this SO question:
[Insert HTML code inside SVG Text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946604/insert-html-code-inside-svg-text-element)