# How to superpose a textarea and a SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to make an animation (With a SVG Path) on a textarea:

I have two div :

Svg :

```
<svg class="graph" width="400px" heigth="100px" viewBox="0 0 400 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="m0,0l400,0l0,100l-400,0l0,-100z" />
</svg>
```

Textarea :

```
<textarea placeholder="message"></textarea>
```

I'm trying to superpose the two element (svg element below the textarea).
The svg will be the border of the textarea.

Here is the codepen of the two element working separately :
http://codepen.io/Dipiks/pen/ogMErr

The SVG react on hover.

Comment: You can't wrap them in a div and use positioning on the `textarea`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert HTML code inside SVG Text element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946604/insert-html-code-inside-svg-text-element)

Comment: You can just set the background of the text-area to be an svg. E.g `<textarea style='background-image: url(nameOfYourSvgHere.svg);'></textarea>`

Answer (score 2):

You may just use backgrounds and animate them :

```css
textarea{
  resize:none;
  border:none;
  border-radius:0;
  width:400px;
  height:100px;
  left:10px;
  position:relative;
  display:block;
  text-align:left;
  cursor:left;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to left, black, black)  no-repeat,    
    linear-gradient(to top, black, black)  no-repeat,    
    linear-gradient(to right, black, black) no-repeat,    
    linear-gradient(to bottom, black, black)  no-repeat
    ;
  background-position: left bottom  ,right 100px , 500px top,left -100px ; 
  background-size: 100% 2px, 2px 100%;
  animation : bordout 0.5s linear reverse;
}
textarea:hover {
  animation : bordin 0.5s linear forwards;
}
@keyframes bordin {
  33% {
    background-position: left bottom  ,right 0, 500px top, left -100px;
  } 
  66% {
    background-position: left bottom  ,right 0 , 0 top, left -100px;
  }
  100%  {
    background-position: left bottom  ,right 0 , 0 top, left 0;
  }
}
@keyframes bordout {
  33% {
    background-position: left bottom  ,right 0, 500px top, left -100px;
  } 
  66% {
    background-position: left bottom  ,right 0 , 0 top, left -100px;
  }
  100%  {
    background-position: left bottom  ,right 0 , 0 top, left 0;
  }

}
```

```html
<textarea placeholder="message"></textarea>
```

or inside a [codepen](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/bNjvgr) (with auto prefix) to play with

Comment: you may add padding according to background-size ,thickness of the visual borders