# Partially clip textarea text with geometric shape as the clip (JavaScript/HTML)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have tens to hundreds of small textareas on a page, and a canvas element with geometric shapes (circles, triangles, rounded rectangles). Each textarea has a corresponding shape as its background. The shapes have a z-index, which can change.

Other than creating tens to hundreds of canvas elements for each shape-textarea, and setting the z-index's correctly, **is there a way to define a polygonal area of a textarea in which the text does not render inside, but does outside of that area?**

For example, If we place a circle in the middle of this question, the text does not render in that circle - but this needs to work for hundreds of textareas.

Comment: If you want to achieve this, it is possible to generate a canvas for each element, draw a shape in it, and set the css z-index for each canvas and corresponding text element, and the shapes will have a transparent background and so will clip the text elements beneath. May have lag issues updated many elements though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to superpose a textarea and a SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28859091/how-to-superpose-a-textarea-and-a-svg)