# how to add html as text to d3.js tree node

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

```
nodeEnter.append("text")
            .attr("x", rectW / 2)
            .attr("y", rectH / 2)
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("text-anchor", "middle").html("<table><tr><td> First Lin</td></tr></table>");
```

You can see my code above. I add a text as html by using `html`. However I can see that htmls as inspecting, there is no text on node. Do you have any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use the `foreignObject` tag, as shown on this page:

[Insert HTML code inside SVG Text element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946604/insert-html-code-inside-svg-text-element)

Either you didn't do any research, or I didn't understand your question ;)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Just completing the answer. Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38437834/append-foreignobject-containing-some-html-inside-an-svg-element