# Append foreignObject containing some HTML inside an SVG element

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Is there any way to append a `foreignObject` element containing some simple HTML to an svg element? Here's the code I tried:

```
 var foreignObject = document.createElement('foreignObject');
 foreignObject.setAttribute('height', '300');
 foreignObject.setAttribute('width', '300');
 var div = document.createElement('div');
 div.innerHTML = 'Hello World';
 foreignObject.appendChild(div); 
 svg.appendChild(foreignObject); //svg is an already created svg element containing a d3 chart
```

But the svg remains the same even after this code executes. Is there anything else that I need to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot to attach the namespace to the `<foreignObject>` Element:

```js
var ns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
var svg = document.querySelector( 'svg' );

var foreignObject = document.createElementNS( ns, 'foreignObject');
foreignObject.setAttribute('height', 300);
foreignObject.setAttribute('width', 300);

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = 'Hello World';

foreignObject.appendChild( div ); 
svg.appendChild(foreignObject); //svg is an already created svg element containing a d3 chart
```

```html
<svg></svg>
```

Answer (score 13):

You don't need `document.createElementNS` or `document.createElement`, you can simply append the `foreignObject` using your D3 selection.

This is an example borrowed from Bostock, D3 creator:

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 960)
    .attr("height", 500);
svg.append("foreignObject")
    .attr("width", 480)
    .attr("height", 500)
  .append("xhtml:div")
    .style("font", "14px 'Helvetica Neue'")
    .html("<h1>An HTML Foreign Object in SVG</h1><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec eu enim quam. ");
</script>
```

Comment: this does not work for me.. html is coming out as a string.

Comment: Well, you can clearly see in the snippet that it works. If you have a specific situation, I suggest you post a new question regarding it with the relevant details.