# HTML inside SVG

Tags: html, svg

I would like to add some HTML markup in an `SVG` drawing.

[image: html-in-svg]

As far as I know, this is not possible with `SVG`.

The image gets displayed in the browser.

Is there a way to paint the `HTML` above the `SVG`?

Since I want to use the `CSS/table` features of `HTML` the `SVG` `<text>` element is not enough.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946604/insert-html-code-inside-svg-text-element

Comment: You can use [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) to include HTML elements. Also if you want to add some text you can use the svg `<text>` and `<tspan>`

Comment: @enxaneta I updated the question: I would like to use css for the html.

Comment: @Andrew no, this is not a duplicate. This other question is only about a link in a SVG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go!

```css
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.text{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="red" stroke-width="4" fill="blue" />
</svg>
<div class="text">
TEXT
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not placing HTML *inside* SVG, but HTML *on top* of SVG, and you are placing the HTML element independently from the SVG content.

This will not work, if the SVG is more complex and you need to position the HTML element *in relation to* some inner SVG element.

Comment: You are right, technically speaking it is on top, not inside. However, in 99% of the cases this will work for UI elements + I would argue that it is the best solution for SEO and alternative layouts like printer and reader view. Also, it is better for accessibility.

Comment: First, I do think this is a good solution -- and in the visual sense, even though it is logically layered, once rasterized into the framebuffer it is surrounded by the shape. BuuuUUUut.. it is not quite ideal. Generically centering + relative positioning is mostly useful to provide visual framing -- however content is not clipped at the SVG. There's really a more important factor: This works for most use cases because we haven't *built* those use cases, but is the UX better? RaphaelJS and D3.js are excellent examples of what *could* be done via elements and CSS with better SVG / HTML interop

Answer (score 16):

User @enxaneta pointed me to [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject).

It works fine (even in webbrowser Edge).

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style>
div {
  color: white;
  font: 18px serif;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
  </style>
 
  <polygon points="5,5 195,10 185,185 10,195" />

  <!-- Common use case: embed HTML text into SVG -->
  <foreignObject x="20" y="20" width="160" height="160">
<!--
  In the context of SVG embedded in an HTML document, the XHTML 
  namespace could be omitted, but it is mandatory in the 
  context of an SVG document
-->
<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  Sed mollis mollis mi ut ultricies. Nullam magna ipsum,
  porta vel dui convallis, rutrum imperdiet eros. Aliquam
  erat volutpat.
</div>
  </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/guettli/pen/RwwBxQL

Answer (score 3):

> Since I want to use the css features of HTML the svg `<text>` element is not enough.

You can use CSS on `<text>`, or really any SVG element. The only major difference is that you have to use `fill` instead of `color` if you need to change the text color. *Where* that CSS would live would depend on how you plan on implementing the image on the site. If the SVG is embedded, ie via an `<img>` tag, the styles would have to be inlined into the SVG file itself, using a `<defs>` tag, as seen below.

```html
<svg width="400" height="110">
<defs>
<style>
.my-custom-text {
fill: #fff;
font-weight: bold;
}
.cyan {
fill: #0ff;
}
</style>
</defs>
<g>
  <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  <text x="15" y="25" class="my-custom-text">My custom <tspan class="cyan">text</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

If you are inlining the SVG, then you can actually think of it as running as HTML -- it, and its child elements, are just normal HTML elements and can be targeted just like any other element. This means that the CSS can be put anywhere you would normally put it - as an external document or in any `<style>` tag.

And if all else fails, you can always just absolutely position the HTML content above the image in a separate container and style it that way.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Nevertheless I still want HTML. I want all the options I have in HTML. For example tables.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you have to do is give the svg `position: absolute` and then you can place markup on top of it. I don't know if there is any way to do it within the svg tag, if that was what you wanted.