# Do web-crawlers find content inside SVG?

Tags: svg, googlebot, google-crawlers

SVG support of current browsers is good.

Even [foreignObject](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject) is supported.

See related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58802113/633961

This way you can insert HTML into SVG and create artistic valueable web pages.

BUT: Do web-crawlers (mainly google's spider) find and index my content which is on the page via a foreignObject (HTML) inside SVG. With the SVG being on a HTML page?

With other words: Would google index "Lorem ipsum dolor..." in above Stackoverflow answer?