# Use of foreignobject inside svg

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I am trying to learn how to animate SVG using CSS.

I am new to this and I am scrubbing the internet to pick up material.

My end goal is to generate an automated svg in .svg format as the program where I upload this animated end product only accepts .svg file.

I have recently come across the code below in an .html file

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">

     <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Document</title>
     <style>
      * {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      
      body {
       background-color: cornsilk;
      }
      
      .container {
       padding: 20px;
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
       min-height: 100vh;
      }
      
      .container svg {
       height: 50vh;
       border: 1px solid;
       padding: 10px;
      }
      
      .heart {
       fill: #D75A4A;
       stroke: #fff;
       animation: stroke-anim 2s infinite alternate, heart-scaling 2s infinite alternate, heart-fill 3s infinite alternate;
       transform-origin: 50%;
       transition: all 0.5s;
      }
      
        
      @keyframes stroke-anim {
       0% {
        stroke-dasharray: 157px 157px;
        stroke-dashoffset: 157px;
       }
       100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
        stroke-dasharray: 5px 2px;
       }
      }
      
      @keyframes heart-scaling {
       0% {
        transform: scale(0.5);
       }
       100% {
        transform: scale(1);
       }
      }
      
      @keyframes heart-fill {
       0% {
        fill: Aquamarine;
       }
       25% {
        fill: Brown;
       }
       50% {
        fill: DarkGrey;
       }
       75% {
        fill: DarkOrange;
       }
       100% {
        fill: DarkTurquoise;
       }
      }
     </style>
    </head>
    <!--#D75A4A;-->

    <body>
     <div class="container">
      <svg viewBox="0 0 50 50">
       <path class="heart" d="M24.85,10.126c2.018-4.783,6.628-8.125,11.99-8.125c7.223,0,12.425,6.179,13.079,13.543
     c0,0,0.353,1.828-0.424,5.119c-1.058,4.482-3.545,8.464-6.898,11.503L24.85,48L7.402,32.165c-3.353-3.038-5.84-7.021-6.898-11.503
     c-0.777-3.291-0.424-5.119-0.424-5.119C0.734,8.179,5.936,2,13.159,2C18.522,2,22.832,5.343,24.85,10.126z" /> </svg>
     </div>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Since I can't use .html for my purpose, I tried to see if I can use a foreignobject to append the div inside svg so that I can still use the css styling. I came across this article ([HTML inside SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58767466/html-inside-svg)) and altered the code to the following. I have realized that it is little easier to animate using a div through CSS as it was done in the initial code.

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1280" height="720">

               
      <style>
      * {
       margin: 0;
       padding: 0;
       box-sizing: border-box;
      }
        div {
       background-color: blueviolet;
      }  
     .container {
       padding: 20px;
       display: flex;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: center;
       min-height: 100vh;
      } 
       .container svg {
       height: 50vh;
       border: 1px solid;
       padding: 10px;
      }
       .heart {
       fill: #D75A4A;
       stroke: #fff;
       animation: stroke-anim 2s infinite alternate, heart-scaling 2s infinite alternate, heart-fill 3s infinite alternate;
       transform-origin: 50%;
       transition: all 0.5s;
      }
        @keyframes stroke-anim {
       0% {
        stroke-dasharray: 157px 157px;
        stroke-dashoffset: 157px;
       }
       100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
        stroke-dasharray: 5px 2px;
       }
      }
      
      @keyframes heart-scaling {
       0% {
        transform: scale(0.5);
       }
       100% {
        transform: scale(1);
       }
      }
      
      @keyframes heart-fill {
       0% {
        fill: Aquamarine;
       }
       25% {
        fill: Brown;
       }
       50% {
        fill: DarkGrey;
       }
       75% {
        fill: DarkOrange;
       }
       100% {
        fill: DarkTurquoise;
       }
      }
      </style>
     
       <foreignobject class="box" x="0" y="0" width="1280" height="720">
        
         <div class="container">
      <svg viewBox="-10 -10 100 100">
       <path class="heart" d="M24.85,10.126c2.018-4.783,6.628-8.125,11.99-8.125c7.223,0,12.425,6.179,13.079,13.543
     c0,0,0.353,1.828-0.424,5.119c-1.058,4.482-3.545,8.464-6.898,11.503L24.85,48L7.402,32.165c-3.353-3.038-5.84-7.021-6.898-11.503
     c-0.777-3.291-0.424-5.119-0.424-5.119C0.734,8.179,5.936,2,13.159,2C18.522,2,22.832,5.343,24.85,10.126z" /> </svg>
     </div>                
       </foreignobject>
      </svg>
```

But it does not render at all in .svg format.  But if I put the same code inside `<html> </html>` tag it works. I am not sure what I am doing wrong or whether I am trying to achieve which is not possible.

If you can please shed me some insight would help me a lot.

Thank you in advance.

By the way, from the example link I took the following portion to see if it renders as  a .svg file and it does.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <style>
    div {
      color: white;
      font: 18px serif;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
    }
      </style>
     
      <polygon points="5,5 195,10 185,185 10,195" />

      <!-- Common use case: embed HTML text into SVG -->
      <foreignObject x="20" y="20" width="160" height="160">
    <!--
      In the context of SVG embedded in an HTML document, the XHTML 
      namespace could be omitted, but it is mandatory in the 
      context of an SVG document
    -->
    <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      TRY.
    </div>
      </foreignObject>
    </svg>
```

Comment: you can use css styles inside the svg element by puting the css roules inside a `<style>` element like so: ` <style type="text/css">
        <![CDATA[
          /*styles*/
        ]]> 
  </style>`

Comment: @enxaneta i tried what you suggested by altering the code as `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1280" height="720"><style type="text/css"><![CDATA[
      * {margin: 0;
       padding: 0......100% {
        fill: DarkTurquoise;
       }
      }
      ]]></style>` and saved it as .svg file.But it does not render. Can you please point me what I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've commented you have to use css styles inside the svg element by puting the css roules inside a  block like so:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
<![CDATA[
 /*styles*/
 ]]> 
</style>
```

Next comes your example with the css code inside the svg element

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <style type="text/css">
    <![CDATA[
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    body {
      background-color: cornsilk;
    }

    .container {
      padding: 20px;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      min-height: 100vh;
    }

    .container svg {
      height: 50vh;
      border: 1px solid;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .heart {
      fill: #D75A4A;
      stroke: #fff;
      animation: stroke-anim 2s infinite alternate, heart-scaling 2s infinite alternate, heart-fill 3s infinite alternate;
      transform-origin: 50%;
      transition: all 0.5s;
    }


    @keyframes stroke-anim {
      0% {
        stroke-dasharray: 157px 157px;
        stroke-dashoffset: 157px;
      }

      100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
        stroke-dasharray: 5px 2px;
      }
    }

    @keyframes heart-scaling {
      0% {
        transform: scale(0.5);
      }

      100% {
        transform: scale(1);
      }
    }

    @keyframes heart-fill {
      0% {
        fill: Aquamarine;
      }

      25% {
        fill: Brown;
      }

      50% {
        fill: DarkGrey;
      }

      75% {
        fill: DarkOrange;
      }

      100% {
        fill: DarkTurquoise;
      }
    }
    ]]>
  </style>
  <path class="heart" d="M24.85,10.126c2.018-4.783,6.628-8.125,11.99-8.125c7.223,0,12.425,6.179,13.079,13.543
     c0,0,0.353,1.828-0.424,5.119c-1.058,4.482-3.545,8.464-6.898,11.503L24.85,48L7.402,32.165c-3.353-3.038-5.84-7.021-6.898-11.503
     c-0.777-3.291-0.424-5.119-0.424-5.119C0.734,8.179,5.936,2,13.159,2C18.522,2,22.832,5.343,24.85,10.126z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: thanks now I see what you mean, I am new to CSS and hence had trouble deciphering what you meant. Thank you very much for the help. As I move along this journey I might have some more questions. But as of now thanks for your time and help !!!

Comment: sorry to be a pain. I have a follow-up question for you. I tried your solution. When I open this .svg file on the brower (chrome, edge) the animation applies but I am not 100% sure if other CSS properties are applied as well. For example, the svg renders on a white background on a chrome. Do you know why is that? Thank you in advance once again.

Comment: Can you ask this as a different question and add a code example?

Comment: sure no problem.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60516415/css-style-not-rendering